# C++ map<string, function>

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have what appears to be a working block of code, but does not work. The purpose is a string is entered by the user and then the program searches the map for the associated function to call it. When i enter a string, it doesn't do anything.

main.cpp

```
#include "getTime.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef string KeyType;
typedef void(getTime::*DoFunc)(void);
typedef pair<const KeyType, DoFunc> Pair;
typedef map<KeyType, DoFunc> mapTimeCall;

int main() {

    string input;
    getTime* getTheTime;

    mapTimeCall callTimeMap;

    callTimeMap.insert(Pair("printCurrentTime()", &getTime::printCurrentTime));
    callTimeMap.insert(Pair("printCurrentDate()", &getTime::printCurrentDate));

    cout << "Enter command: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << endl;

    mapTimeCall::const_iterator x;

    x = callTimeMap.find(input);

    if (x != callTimeMap.end()) {
        (*x).second;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I changed `(*x).second;` to `getTheTime.*(x->second)();` and i get the error `Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to) function type`

getTime.h

```
#ifndef H_getTime
#define H_getTime

#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class getTime {

public:
    void printCurrentTime();
    void printCurrentDate();

private:
    string currentTime;
    string currentDate;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    string strMonth;
    time_t now;
    struct tm *current;

}; 

#endif
```

Comment: You are not calling the function anywhere. And if you do, you will need an instance of `getTime ` to call it on.

Comment: There has been a shortage of working crystal balls recently, so there might be people who don't know what behavior you expect from the program just by staring at the code. Would you give us some more info besides "doesn't work"?

Comment: I changed the question a little. Should be more to your liking. I edited the line where i have `(*x).second;` to `getTheTime.*(x->second)();` which give me an error as stated above in edited question.

Comment: _"I have what appears to be a working block of code, but does not work."_ I guess appearances can be deceiving, or something..?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the function.

1. Function calls require parentheses to denote the arguments (if any) that are passed.  Your attempt doesn't show this.
2. To call a non-static member function via pointer, you must call it with an instance of the object.  You failed to do that.

Here is a full example, please note the changes:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct getTime
{
    void printCurrentTime() { std::cout << "Here is the time\n"; }
    void printCurrentDate() { std::cout << "Here is the date\n"; }
};

typedef void(getTime::*DoFunc)(void);
typedef std::pair<std::string, DoFunc> Pair;
typedef std::map<std::string, DoFunc> mapTimeCall;

int main() 
{
    getTime getTheTime;
    getTime* pGetTheTime = &getTheTime;
    mapTimeCall callTimeMap;
    callTimeMap.insert(Pair("printCurrentTime()", &getTime::printCurrentTime));
    callTimeMap.insert(Pair("printCurrentDate()", &getTime::printCurrentDate));
    mapTimeCall::const_iterator x;
    x = callTimeMap.find("printCurrentTime()");

    if (x != callTimeMap.end()) 
    {
        (getTheTime.*(x->second))();  // call using object
        (pGetTheTime->*(x->second))();  // call using pointer
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Here is the time
Here is the time
```

The basic syntax of calling a non-static member function via pointer is:

```
(object.*fnPtr)(args);
```

or if object is a pointer:

```
(object->*fnPtr)(args);
```

Since `x->second` is your function pointer, that is what `fnPtr` will represent.

Comment: For clarity, since the operator precedences regarding pointer access and ptr_to_mem_fun-access operators are not an everyday topic, I recommend adding parentheses around the function pointer: `(getTheTime.*(x->second))()` and `(pGetTheTime->*(x->second))()` or preferably use a dedicated variable for the function pointer: `DoFunc fnPtr = x->second; (getTheTime.*fnPtr)();`

Comment: Edited the answer to add the parentheses.